# Does a multi-engine rating propagate down from commercial to private?

Tags: faa-regulations, far-61, multi-engine

I have a private pilot license with airplane single engine land and instrument ratings. I'm about to get the commercial with a airplane multi engine land class rating.

Let's say I'm not currently flying for hire and my second class medical is more than a year old, so I cannot exercise my commercial privileges. Can I then legally fly a multi-engine plane exercising my private privileges, carrying, say, a friend or other non-paying passengers in a part-91 operation?

In other words, does the class-rating propagate down to my private?

Comment: please consider marking the answer correct. thanks

Comment: I already accepted an answer as correct, and that answer has since disappeared (apparently deleted by author). I'm marking your answer as correct now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note [Part 61.31(c)](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFar.nsf/daa4c54debeb6dca86256f3400626ab0/15c90b07303160f48625793b0068f317!OpenDocument):

> (c) Aircraft category, class, and type ratings: Limitations on the
>   carriage of persons, or operating for compensation or hire. Unless a
>   person holds a category, class, and type rating (if a class and type
>   rating is required) that applies to the aircraft, **that person may not
>   act as pilot in command of an aircraft that is carrying another
>   person**, or is operated for compensation or hire. That person also may
>   not act as pilot in command of that aircraft for compensation or hire.

Since you will have the Category and Class rating, then you may carry another person.

Your old license says:

```
Private Pilot
Airplane Single-engine Land
Instrument Airplane
```

Your new license will say:

```
Commercial Pilot  
Airplane Multi-engine Land  
Instrument Airplane   

Private Privileges  
Airplane Single-engine Land
```

You may fly under part 91 ASEL, AMEL, and IFR

You may fly part 119 or 135 (or other commercial operations) AMEL and IFR<sup>1</sup>. You may NOT fly part 119 or 135 or any commercial operations ASEL. If you want to fly ASEL in a commercial operation, you will need to upgrade your ASEL by passing another commercial checkride in an ASEL.

This is the back of my certificate. I took the ASES checkride when I had a Private certificate.
[image: Sample Certificate]

---

1. Assuming you have the correct medical and any other checkouts you may need

Comment: Stated differently, a commercial certificate also conveys privileges of a private pilot certificate.