# If a pilot takes a MEL checkride and later a SES checkride, is the pilot now also qualified for MES/SEL?

Tags: pilot-certification, checkride

**Assuming all checkrides are passed.*

If a pilot gets a multi-engine land rating on a primary checkride, and later takes a checkride as single-engine sea, is the pilot now qualified for multi-engine sea and single-engine land?

I suppose an unspoken question would be, does a multi-engine rating automatically allow for single-engine PIC privileges, or is the restriction between single and multi-engine a 2-way street?

Comment: Related, very nearly a dupe: [Why do multi-engine privileges not propagate down to single engine?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25163/why-do-multi-engine-privileges-not-propagate-down-to-single-engine/25165#25165)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You must take the training and pass the practical test for each add-on rating. See [14 CFR 61.63(c)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=21aaa03904ea032b261bab32f26e7f88&mc=true&node=se14.2.61_163&rgn=div8).